# Can not connect to Tor even with Bridges

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, bridge

I have tried many versions of the Tor, even with the latest bridges.
But still bootstrap is stuck at 10-85%.. and I can not connect to Tor network.
please help me fix this issue and what to do?
thanks

Comment: Do you use the Tor Browser Bundle? Which operating system? What kind of bridges do you use? Please edit your post and provide us with some more information.

Comment: One way to eliminate the rudimentary problems is to try a newest version of Tor browser, start it and wait until it stuck at x%. Then close the program and after few second restart the Tor browser. This may solve some of the problems you may experience.

Comment: thanks for your reply sir.. and sorry for lack of information.
Yes, i use tor browser bundle ( from old to the latest version, i have tried all of that but result is negative), windows 8.1 but it also isnt connecting either in win 7, i use bridges which we get by email, still cant connect using that. 
@Roya  i have tried this. but still the same problem.

Comment: Add more bridges and try again. Check you Tor log to see if there is any error/warning messages. I guess your system clock isn't correct.

Comment: @hemant TBB allows you to use pre-configured bridges. There you can choose between obfs3, flashproxy and others. Please try those options and see if one of them works.